# How to create a string from one char with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to create a `string` from one char with `JavaScript`?

This is `C#`.

```
String text = new String('*',20);
```

Is there an easy way to do this with `JavaScript`?

Comment: If that's a JavaScript question, please state the goal, not a code you want ported from another language.

Comment: From his given example, he wants an easy code in JS that creates a string "********************"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could join an array

```
var text = new Array(20).join('*');

// returns ********************
```

Comment: @rlemon +1 for confusing SO with reddit

Comment: @MBottens no confusion. people on Reddit are nicer :P